# How can I open Terminator with mutiple windows already open

Tags: terminator

When I run Terminator i want it to open up already split vertically 8[image] time.  I want this to be my default layout everytime I open terminator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After setting up your terminals how you want them, right click anywhere, select preferences, then go to the layouts tab. From here click “Add”, and a layout will be created with your current settings, so if you have the six split when you do this, you can save it to load it like that everytime. Hope this helps

Comment: Mhmhm it's not working, but it did save the tabs but when i close and reopen Terminator the tabs go away :/ cheers for the help though!

Comment: How do i make the 8 split my default layout when i open it?

Comment: just open up 8 splits, and make the layout, Cheers, hopefully it will work this time!

Comment: Omg yes! Sorry i missed out a step haha and i named the new layout default which turned it to my default layout :D THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME OUT!! I literally was there for about an hour trying to sort it out haha, thanks again, Nick! :D

Comment: Tis fine, glad i could help! :D

Comment: :D ooo one more question, do you know how i can open it with text already inputted so i don't have to type them in? THANKS! :D

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/hls2e1lx9/ There ya go, text already inputted! Hope this helps!